# Itext - How to underline half line?

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a PDF using iText. I want to underline half text of paragraph up to the end of line includingу empty space.

How can I achieve this?

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase("Help me ");
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.add(phrase);
    Phrase phrase1 = new Phrase("pls");
    LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
    ls.setOffset(-2);
    phrase1.add(ls);
    p.add(phrase1);
    document.add(p);
    document.close();
}
```

Comment: In the paragraph you can add a Font.

Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a paragraph", new
 Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 18, Font.BOLDITALIC, new BaseColor(0, 0, 255)) ); use a font that is underlined. samples here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-11

Comment: I want to underline space that there is after the text also. It will not be underline using font style. I've tried to do it and added "new Chunk(new LineSeparator());", but lines are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You have an `ls` instance created like this:

```
LineSeparator ls = new LineSeparator();
```

You want the line to span half of the available width. That can be done with the `setPercentage()` method:

```
ls.setPercentage(50);
```